# Evaluate classifier based on predicted probabilities?

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, accuracy

If I had a categorical response $Y$ and multiple categorical features $X$, and I wanted to fit a model to predict $Y$.

If all I cared about was the eventual distribution of $Y$ (say in terms of %), I was wondering if I could use that criteria somehow to evaluate my model, rather than use the actual predicted class label.

Originally I thought maybe, if I fitted some model e.g.

```
library(randomForest)
y <- factor(sample(seq(3), 100, replace = TRUE))
x <- matrix(sample(seq(5), 500, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)
x <- data.frame(apply(x, 2, as.factor))

rf <- randomForest(y ~ ., data = x)
```

Then I could get the ratio like

```
  test_probs <- predict(rf, x, type = "prob")
  test_ratio <- colSums(test_probs)
  test_ratio <- test_ratio / sum(test_ratio)
```

and e.g. calculate the MSE on it. But of course inside a CV loop. But even then, of course the distribution throughout the CV folds will always be very similar. Would this be usable if I set the number of folds so high that the variance is very high, or is it always a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluating predictive distributions instead of predicted single class memberships is an enormously good idea. Quality measures for such predictive distributions are called [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules). You specifically want so-called *proper* scoring rules, which are the ones that reward you for finding the correct distribution. [The scoring rules tag wiki has more information and pointers to literature.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info)

Related and possibly enlightening: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) and [Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352)